# Objective-C equivalent of Haskell's intersperse function? or join objects on another object?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

Is there some native objective c method that's similar to Haskell's intersperse function?

Here's an example

```
Prelude> Data.List.intersperse ',' "abcdefg"
"a,b,c,d,e,f,g"
```

Or maybe some function that joins objects on another object? I know I can do it manually by looping over the collection, I'm just wondering if there's some functional built-in that serves this use case

I have some `UIBarButtonItem` objects,
`[barButtonItem1,barButtonItem2,barButtonItem3]`

I want to end up with:
`[barButtonItem1,flexButtonItem,barButtonItem2,flexButtonItem,barButtonItem3]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick Google for such a function turned up an `NSArray+FunctionalKit.h` that implements the `intersperse` function you desire. Given that this exists, I'm tempted to say that there is no built-in function that does it. You could add this to your projects:

```
@interface NSArray (Intersperse)
- (NSArray *)intersperse:(id)object;
@end

@implementation NSArray (Intersperse)
- (NSArray *)intersperse:(id)object {
  NSMutableArray *interspersed = [NSMutableArray array];
  for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [self count]; ++i) {
    [interspersed addObject:[self objectAtIndex:i]];
    if (i != [self count] - 1) [interspersed addObject:object];
  }    
  return [NSArray arrayWithArray:interspersed];
}
@end
```

Usage:

```
NSArray *buttons = @[barButtonItem1,barButtonItem2,barButtonItem3];
NSArray *allButtons = [buttons intersperse:flexButtonItem];
```

The whole GitHub project is [available](https://github.com/mogeneration/functionalkit/).